# How to get record in larval using where() function and passing a variable as the value

Tags: php, database, laravel

This problem is killing me. I have looked at the documentation and can't find what I need.

```
$item = Item::all();
    foreach($item as $i){

        //Getting the max historical price
        $history = HistoricalPrice::all()->whereIn('item_id',use($i->id));
```

Alternatively I tried:

```
$history = HistoricalPrice::all()->where('item_id', '=', '$i->id');
```

Basically, I need to find all records in a database that have this specific id. I have tried using the where and wherein function, but when you have to put in the "value", I cannot pass the variable $I->id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `whereIn` for single comparisons and `=` is the default operator. So you can just do:

```
$history = HistoricalPrice::where('item_id', $i->id)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately that did not work. I tried that and I did not get anything. However when I use the all() function, I get all of them. So I dont think that it is a database problem. I think that it might be a php problem.

Comment: @TotiCuervo That's doubtful to be honest. hard code the ID of an entry in the `where` to confirm it's working correclty.

Comment: It worked when I specifically put the number in! Still not sure why it wont work when I pass the $I->id.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you for the help!